# Lua API evaluates variable name instead of value

Tags: c, api, lua

I'm using the Lua 5.2 C API.  I am trying to get a function to accept a string variable or a string literal.

this code:

```
static int printTest(lua_State *L)
{   
    size_t lslen = NULL;
    const char *lsrc = lua_tolstring(L, 0, &lslen);
    printf("%s\n", lsrc);
}
/* ----- Registration array ----- */
static const luaL_Reg testhook[] = {
        {"printTest", printTest},
        {NULL, NULL} /* sentinel */
};    
/* ----- Registration function ----- */    
LUALIB_API int registerTestHookFunctions(lua_State *L)
{
    lua_newtable(L); 
    lua_setglobal(L, "hook"); 
    lua_getglobal(L, "hook"); 
    luaL_setfuncs(L, testhook, 0); 
    lua_settop(L, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

when run from Lua, will do this:

```
hook.printTest('hello')  -- prints 'hello'
a = 'hello'
hook.printTest(a) -- prints 'a'
```

I'm very new to Lua and using this documentation: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html
and am not finding/understanding how to discern a variable from a literal.  (There are no lua_isliteral() or lua_isvariable() methods, for example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have passed a bad index to `lua_tolstring`. The reference manual clearly states that

> 0 is never an acceptable index.

You use negative indices for relative values, and positive indices for absolute values. Neither of those conditions is ever 0.

Comment: Sigh.  Embarrassingly obvious now that I see it.  Thanks.